# How to create a lightbox on calling the href of a attribute on click of a image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following structure for my lightbox and it works like a charm. Here is the code for my lightbox.

```
<ul class="thumbnail">
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/1/"/></a>

    </li>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/2/"/></a>

    </li>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/3/"/></a>

    </li>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/4/"/></a>

    </li>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/5/"/></a>

    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="light-box">
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/1/"/></a>

    </li>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/2/"/></a>

    </li>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/3/"/></a>

    </li>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/4/"/></a>

    </li>
    <li><a><img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/5/"/></a>

    </li>
</ul>
<div class="next">next</div>
<div class="prev">prev</div>
<div class="close">X</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function () {
    var currentIndex = 0,
        lightboxLis = $(".light-box li");

    $('.thumbnail li').click(function () {
        currentIndex = $(this).index();
        lightboxLis.hide();
        lightboxLis.eq(currentIndex).show();

        //put next prev show here otherwise it won't work due to your hover
        //when you hover the next prev button in your old version you no longer hover the li so can't click on the button
        $('.next, .prev, .close').show();

        //add the hide of next prev to when you close the lightbox
    });
    $('.close').click(function () {
        lightboxLis.hide();
        $('.next, .prev, .close').hide();
    });

    $('.next').click(function () {
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex == lightboxLis.length) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }

        lightboxLis.hide();
        lightboxLis.eq(currentIndex).show();
    });

    $('.prev').click(function () {
        currentIndex--;
        if (currentIndex < 0) {
            currentIndex = lightboxLis.length - 1;
        }

        lightboxLis.hide();
        lightboxLis.eq(currentIndex).show();
    });
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/ts2jku2x/10/)**

I would like to rather simplify my code for avoiding more mark up. So in that case i have to call my `href` link of the `a` on click of the thumbnail. So I dont come up with any idea. So i will be very thankful that someone shows me a right path how do i do so. Here is the new code block. What Iam trying to achieve.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="thumbnail">
    <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/1/"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/1/"/></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/1/"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/2/"/></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/1/"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/3/"/></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/1/"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/4/"/></a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/1/"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/5/"/></a>

    </li>
</ul>
<div class="next">next</div>
<div class="prev">prev</div>
<div class="close">X</div>
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminthomas/ts2jku2x/11/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use html data attributes to store the url of the big image inside your thumbnail image and insert it with the jquery .html() function.

so if you have your thumbs like that:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150/sports/2/" data-full-img-link="http://lorempixel.com/600/600/sports/2/"/>
```

you create the html string in your js

```
boxContent = "<img src='" + $(this).data("fullImgLink") + "'/>";
//and 'load' it into your light box (in my case it's named imageBox)
$(".imageBox").html(boxContent);
```

since i don't see the point in using ul's in html, with the css list-style-type: none (so in fact, creating a list and saying, it's no list!) i use divs instead. [see the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/0tbcp1rd/)

Comment: Thats really awesome thats the one iam looking after. +1

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset <-- according to this one, yes! 
for my own projects, i don't care. i always take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp and then decide, that i can live with 1 to 2 percent of all users, not being able to surf my webpage

Comment: btw - if that is what you want, just accept it as solution ;)

Comment: Hey errand this is kinda rude but i wanna give some animation on changing of every slides can you help me with further

Comment: To be more specific the animation needs to be a sliding animation. I acheived the fade In and Out effects but Im not happy with that

Comment: hey Ben, sry was offline a few days. do you want a slide left/right or up/down animation?
up/down is already available with jquery, left/right is not. you can use jquery ui for that - or instead build your own slide effect using the jquery animate() function.

Comment: Hey E im sry was offline too. I need to animate the slides from left to right without jquery ui. I wanna use pure jquery or javascript. Could you help with that

Comment: hmmm... this is a tricky one. there are several things to do - since the image stays at full size, but the viewport of the lightbox is dynamic to your browser window (60%), i can't get the correct offset for the animate() function. i'm sorry, but the best would be, to post a new question - i've become daddy last week and therefore have little time right now.

Comment: hey thanks for your valuable answer and comment. Congrats for being a dad. :)